# What do I do about a machine that is running out of memory and crashing?

Tags: freeze, swap

My spouse is running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Thinkpad X1 that has been crashing a lot. Usually he's got a bunch of tabs open but nothing that should crash a relatively powerful laptop.

The machine freezes and the only solution is a power cycle because it is otherwise unresponsive.

I am used to being able to get to another TTY to troubleshoot with ctrl-alt-F3 but that doesn't seem to work on his machine.

One oddity, when I run `top` it reports zero swap:

`KiB Swap: 0 total, 0 free, 0 used`

That can't be right, but `free` confirms it:

```
amanda@Flatbush:~$ sudo free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        5.4G        164M        1.5G        2.1G        516M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

By contrast, my machine is a few years older than his and works fine. There, `free` shows:

```
amanda@mona:~$ sudo free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        1.2G        5.1G        237M        1.3G        5.9G
Swap:          7.8G          0B        7.8G
```

The good machine has way more memory and way more available swap (though to be fair I just fired it up to compare and don't have anything running on it).

I suspect that the issue is connected to the differences in memory but I don't know how to go about fixing it. s

Comment: I'm wondering is there a swap partition on this system?

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar There is a swap partition but it is commented out in `/etc/fstab` and `sudo swapon` shows no results.

Comment: use ``fdisk``, ``cfdisk`` or ``gparted`` to see if that partition really exists on disk. If yes get it running by having the appropriate line inf ``/etc/fstab`` otherwise create a swap file and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description and the `free` output suggest that the system may be crashing when it runs out of RAM, and swap is not enabled. (Browser tabs can sometimes consume a staggering amount of resources)

One easy solution:

- Add a [swap file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F) if there is not an existing swap partition/swapfile.
- Activate swap using `swapon`
- Tell him that when the system gets sluggish it's time to close a few tabs.
- If the system remains sluggish with all tabs closed, bring it to you in the sluggish state.